# Is it possible to use path base route on AWS Load Balancer listener's with S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to write redirect rule from AWS Application Load Balancer to s3 folder.

Assume the bucket name is my-example-bucket, folder name is test, and there're few files under the test folder, so following are sample links and how the URL looks like.

- https://my-example-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/test1.txt
- https://my-example-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/test2.txt
- https://my-example-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test/test3.txt

I also setup a site under AWS Application Load Balancer, assume the URL is [www.my-site.com](http://www.my-site.com). I'd like redirect path [www.my-site.com/test](http://www.my-site.com/test) to the S3 bucket's test folder, so I configure the rule as following, but when I type https://www.my-site.com/test/test1.txt, doesn't seems like working, it looks like only go to the https://my-example-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test. Does AWS application load balancer even support redirect path based route to s3? Or I wonder I'm missing anything here.

[image]

Comment: "it looks like only go to the `https://my-example-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test`" - are you sure about this?. This is not s3 website endpoint. Also s3 websites don't support https.

Comment: I didn't create s3 static website but was just create a public s3 bucket with these files, and I was trying to redirect from the load balancer to the s3 bucket to see if it'll works. It works for individual file path but doesn't seem like works for the folder path.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing like folder in S3. S3 has flat structure and what seems to be be folder is actually only a part of object key. That's why you can not see "folder" content in your browser as it requires some kind of hierachy.